# Connection refused for SSH on Server via Docker container

Tags: 16.04, ssh, docker

I have a server which is running a Docker container, and inside that container is a jupyter notebook, which has been run with the following command:

```
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8882 --no-browser --allow-root
```

I would like to access the notebook from my laptop, but am getting some errors which I have never received before (this has worked in the past)

I initiate an SSH on my laptop by running:

```
ssh -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8882 mrrecon@137.xxx.xxx.xx.
```

I then navigate on my laptop to localhost:8888 and it does not connect. If I look at the error messages, (using verbose -v command), I get:

[image: Error message: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0]

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue was that the the docker was engaged on a specific port and thus I needed to use that port, now the 8882 port that I was using.

Comment: Could you please give us more information and commands to show your step? Thanks!